# Windows 10 automatic repair opens Windows Defender Offline

Tags: windows, windows-10

Whenever I turn on my laptop, I get this message called WatchDog Initializing and it does phase 0 and phase 1 and then stops. I searched online and found what to do. It said force shut down a couple times to get automatic repair but, when it loads, it show WDO. I don't want it to open to WDO, I want it to open the troubleshoot selection. So could someone tell me how to achieve it?

Notes: I updated it from Win7 to Win10 two days ago

I know what is causing WatchDog, it is AVG Antivirus, if I could uninstall it, then I can be on my way.

Comment: Have you tried Safe Mode?

Comment: That is what I am trying to get to. But instead I get WDO

Comment: If you fail to boot Windows three times it takes you to the Advanced Startup Menu.  Have you allowed Windows Defender go ahead and scan your system?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, and it still does watch dog. I'll try to boot it three times as two times get WDO

Comment: Still comes up as Windows Defender. No sign of advance startup menu

Comment: Boot to a Windows 10 Version 1607 installation disk.

Comment: I don't have a disk. I used the Media Creation Tool

Comment: You need a disk to solve your problem.  Download one from Microsoft.